# Filter and update embedded Array in mongodb mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, subdocument

The MongoDb model looks like this :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ee269c949c9d58970528d1e"
    },
    "parent": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ee269c949c9d58970528d1d"
            },
            "uType": "parent",
            "fName": "p1",
            "lName": "p1",
            "num": "123"
        }
    ],
    "child": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ee269c949c9d58970528d1c"
            },
            "uType": "child",
            "fName": "c1",
            "lName": "c1",
            "num": "8963",
            "email": "c1@gmail.com",
            "gender": "male"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have an incoming object that looks like this -

```
{
    "uType":"child",
    "fName": "c2",
    "lName": "c2",
    "num": "98733",
    "email": "c2@gmail.app",
    "invite": {
        "uType": "parent",
        "fName": "p1",
        "lName": "p1",
        "num": "123"
    }
}
```

I have to filter for the incoming object such that I get the response like below- which means for the incoming object, there is a matching parent but there is not a matching child.

Tried using $or and provided multiple conditions but every time ended up getting a record in child array. I gave it a shot using aggregate as well but could not find a possible solution. Can someone tell me what is the best way to do this?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ee269c949c9d58970528d1e"
    },
    "parent": [
        {
            "isActive": false,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ee269c949c9d58970528d1d"
            },
            "uType": "parent",
            "fName": "p1",
            "lName": "p1",
            "num": "123"
        }
    ],
    "child": [ ]
}
```

**UPDATE**: Tried using projection, but still no luck -

```
Model.aggregate([
            {
                $project: {
                    child: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$child",
                            as: "ch",
                            cond: { $eq: ["$ch.num", this.num] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

Comment: is `uType.invite` always `"parent"` and `uType` always `"child"`?

Comment: @thammada - yes

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are *so* close to the solution, if you use `"$$ch.num"` instead of `"$ch.num"` it should work.

```
const match = {
    "uType":"child",
    "fName": "c2",
    "lName": "c2",
    "num": "98733",
    "email": "c2@gmail.app",
    "invite": {
        "uType": "parent",
        "fName": "p1",
        "lName": "p1",
        "num": "123"
    }
}
```

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "parent.num": match.invite.num
        },
        {
          "child.num": match.num
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      parent: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$parent",
          as: "p",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$p.num",
              match.invite.num
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      child: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$child",
          as: "ch",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$ch.num",
              match.num
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But you can do something similar without aggregation, but you will not get an empty array when there is no match, you will just don't get the key.

```
Model.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "parent.num": match.invite.num
    },
    {
      "child.num": match.num
    }
  ]
},
{
  parent: {
    $elemMatch: {
      num: match.invite.num
    },
  },
  child: {
    $elemMatch: {
      num: match.num
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: the second method works well actually, except that I am loosing out other key-value pairs. Only getting parent array in the response. How to keep other keys as well?

Comment: There is no way to do that if you use `.find`. I think you can easily add it in your application layer after you get the result from the query, because you will know for sure if either `parent` or `child` is missing, it should be an empty array.

Comment: Or are there actual cases that `parent` or `child` does not exist?